# If function behave differently in MySQL 5.5.49

Tags: mysql-5.5, stored-procedures

I'm running MySQL 5.5.49 on my Windows 7 32-bit

I'm using a stored procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_testing`(
IN in_param VARCHAR(50)
, OUT out_1 VARCHAR(50)
)
BEGIN

    DECLARE v_no_por_cabang VARCHAR(50);
    DECLARE v_no_por_cabang1 VARCHAR(50);
    DECLARE v_no_por_cabang2 VARCHAR(50);

    SET v_no_por_cabang = in_param;

    SET v_no_por_cabang1 = IF(v_no_por_cabang = 0, NULL, v_no_por_cabang); 

    SET v_no_por_cabang2 = IF(v_no_por_cabang = '0', NULL, v_no_por_cabang); 

    SELECT v_no_por_cabang1;
    SELECT v_no_por_cabang2;

END$$
```

and I'm calling it like this:

```
CALL sp_testing('POR1',@out1);
```

The output for `v_no_por_cabang1` is NULL. The output for `v_no_por_cabang2` is `POR1`.

Why does the IF function behave like that? In my previous test in MySQL 5.5.xx on Ubuntu 12 the same stored procedure didn't behave like that. It returned `POR1` for `v_no_por_cabang1`.

Anybody know why?

Answer (score 0):

It's because in the comparison `v_no_por_cabang = 0` you're converting `v_no_por_cabang` implicitly to a number. When you use single-quotes like in `v_no_por_cabang = '0'` you're correctly comparing two strings.

MySQL also tells you so, when you execute `show warnings;` afterwards. Result:

```
+---------+------+------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                  |
+---------+------+------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'POR1' |
+---------+------+------------------------------------------+
```

Fun fact: When your string starts with a number, MySQL converts the first number part of the string to a number.

```
root@localhost:playground > CALL sp_testing('1POR1',@out1);

+------------------+
| v_no_por_cabang1 |
+------------------+
| 1POR1            |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

+------------------+
| v_no_por_cabang2 |
+------------------+
| 1POR1            |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.01 sec)

root@localhost:playground > CALL sp_testing('0POR1',@out1);
+------------------+
| v_no_por_cabang1 |
+------------------+
| NULL             |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

+------------------+
| v_no_por_cabang2 |
+------------------+
| 0POR1            |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Many thx for the explanation